# How to make many agent typing in the same text field

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, pug, agent

What is the simplest ways to make many agent type in the same text field, with threads i used to pass a `jtextarea` as parameter in the constructor but i don't know  how to do that with jade agents.
any ideas !!!

Here is my code:

class first:

```
    public class first extends Agent {
@Override
protected void setup(){

  addBehaviour(new OneShotBehaviour(){
        @Override
        public void action() {
            System.out.println("enter a number :") ;// entre a number to transmit to agent second
            Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
            int n =in.nextInt();
ACLMessage msg=new ACLMessage(ACLMessage.INFORM);
            msg.setContent(""+n);
            msg.addReceiver(new AID("second",AID.ISLOCALNAME));
            send(msg);//send the msg 
        }});
    addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour() {
        @Override
        public void action(){
            ACLMessage msg1=receive();
            if(msg1!=null){  
           System.out.println("msg receiv :"+msg1.getContent());// print the msg received (here i want to print it in jtextarea)
            }else block();}
    });
}}
```

class second:

```
public class second extends Agent {

@Override
protected void setup(){

    addBehaviour(new CyclicBehaviour() {
        @Override
        public void action(){
            ACLMessage msg=receive();
            if(msg!=null){
              System.out.println("number receiv :"+msg.getContent());// print the msg received (here i want to print it in jtextarea)
             ACLMessage msg1=msg.createReply();
            msg1.setContent(""+Integer.parseInt(msg.getContent())*Integer.parseInt(msg.getContent()));
            send(msg1);
            }else block();
        }
}); 
}
}
```

main class:

```
public class Typing_agents {


   public static void main(String[] args) throws StaleProxyException, InterruptedException {


        Runtime rt = Runtime.instance();
        Profile p = new ProfileImpl(); 
        p.setParameter(Profile.GUI, "true");
        ContainerController cc = rt.createMainContainer(p);
           AgentController first ;
                   AgentController second ;
           first = cc.createNewAgent("first","typing_agents.first",null);
                   second = cc.createNewAgent("second","typing_agents.second",null); 
            first.start();
                second.start();              
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can better understand your question, reproduce your problem and provide a solution.

Comment: this programme is to make a simulation for Lamport algorithme sending request respond with agree and each agent type the content of the messages that it receive ... i finish all the code just that point with the jtextarea i don't know how to make it work , i hope my comment help and sorry for my English.

Comment: *"i hope my comment help"* No, not much. Where is the MCVE suggested by @SergiyMedvynskyy? That would help immensely.

Comment: i edited it , take a look !!

Comment: The problem is, that you use some non-standard libs. So we cannot compile your code.

Comment: yes, it's Java Agent DEvelopment Framework